# How to measure elapsed time with Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, guava

I need to measure how much time it takes to process external service response in Apache Camel.

I've search the web for solutions and surprisingly there was no acceptable one.

Using an [EventNotifier](http://cmoulliard.blogspot.com/2011/02/measure-elapsed-time-with-camel.html) feels too heavy weight and more framework level performance measurement tool.

So I've made my own simple solution, but I'm hoping for something better out there I've missed or at least a constructive feedback.

A solution attempt below.

Comment: You should probably go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that kind of question since you already have an answer.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire We on Code Review need the code to be reviewed to be present in the question. In its current state this question would be off topic. Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: CodeReview is for working, existing, self-maintained code. Which is what this question seems to be about, so that's good! This question would work, provided it merged the question and answer as a question on CodeReview. I don't think that'd be easy to do for a mod, so probably the OP would have to post it themselves...

Comment: Actually I'm interested in input from other Camel users or developers on how to do it better or if this approach is legit.

Answer (score 5):

I think that camel do this by default.

> Available as of Camel 2.12
>   Message History is enabled by default from Camel 2.12. During routing Camel captures how the Exchange is routed, as a org.apache.camel.MessageHistory entity that is stored on the Exchange. On the org.apache.camel.MessageHistory there is information abut the route id, processor id, timestamp, and elapsed time it took to process the Exchange by the processor.

Only that you have to do is get the MessageHistory in your "doFinally" code:

```
List<MessageHistory> list = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.MESSAGE_HISTORY,List.class);
```

There you can get the the elapsed time for each route

Comment: Yes, but the thing is it produces different results than Guava's Stopwatch and honestly I believe more in Guava than Camel accuracy. Also I don't want my feature to be dependent on this particular Camel feature, because we might decide to turn it of at some point for performance reasons.

Comment: Its impossible to have the same results, because camel do Stopwatch before it call the bean(stopwatch, "stop"). But the difference is big?

Comment: Yes, it's order of magnitude, so probably there are some other processing costs involved, that accounts for the difference. In a quick test it was 40 ms vs >300 ms, IIRC

Comment: I've just checked on another example and it seam to be the same within 1 ms.

Comment: I've edited my response, and now I'm really puzzled, looks like I'm missing something simple, or Guava's Stopwatch is broken (very unlikely).

Comment: I cant comment in your answer, that camel dont take the exception handling into account. If you need that you have to use something like your solution but if you dont, camel is the way

Comment: I've ended up using `MessageHistory` and ignoring the exception handling. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how my business logic looks like:

```
from(incomingUri).routeId(ROUTE_ID)
            ...
            .doTry()
                .bean(stopwatch, "start")
                .to(externalService)
            .doCatch(NoHttpResponseException.class, ProtocolException.class, IOException.class)
                .process(externalServiceExceptionProcessor(ERROR_MESSAGE_SERVICE_NOT_RESPONDING))
            .doFinally()
                .bean(stopwatch, "stop")
            .end()
            ...
```

The `Stopwatch` bean instantition:

```
StopWatchBean stopwatch = new StopWatchBean(new ExchangeConsumer<Stopwatch>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Exchange exchange, Stopwatch stopwatch) {
            Long taken = stopwatch.elapsed(MILLISECONDS);
            exchange.setProperty(RESPONSE_TIME, constant(taken));
        }
});
```

and class definition:

```
public class StopWatchBean {

    private final Stopwatch stopwatch;
    private final ExchangeConsumer<Stopwatch> onStopFunction;

    public StopWatchBean(ExchangeConsumer<Stopwatch> onStopFunction) {
        this.stopwatch = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
        this.onStopFunction = onStopFunction;
    }

    public void stop(Exchange exchange) {
        if (!stopwatch.isRunning()) {
            return;
        }
        stopwatch.stop();
        onStopFunction.accept(exchange, stopwatch);
    }

    public void start(Exchange unused) {
        stopwatch.start();
    }

    public void reset(Exchange unused) {
        stopwatch.reset();
    }

}
```

The `Stopwatch` is from Guava and the Consumer is just a custom functional interface.

Waiting for comments.

EDIT:
I've added some simple code, like:

```
started = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
stopped = System.currentTimeMillis();

elapsed = stopped - started;
```

and made some measurements, on normal case looks good:

```
[xxxxxxxxxProxy    ] [stopWatchStart    ] [bean[StopWatchBean{elapsed=100, stopwatch=100.8 ms}]                          ] [         1]
[xxxxxxxxxProxy    ] [toXxxxxxxxxx      ] [https://127.0.0.1:5680/xxxxxxxxx?throwExceptionOnFailure=false&bridgeEndpoint=] [       100]
[xxxxxxxxxProxy    ] [stopWatchStop     ] [bean[StopWatchBean{elapsed=100, stopwatch=100.8 ms}]                          ] [         3]
```

and on error/exception is different:

```
[xxxxxxxxxProxy    ] [stopWatchStart    ] [bean[StopWatchBean{elapsed=38, stopwatch=344.1 ms}]                           ] [         1]
[xxxxxxxxxProxy    ] [toXxxxxxxxxx      ] [https://127.0.0.1:5680/xxxxxxxxx?throwExceptionOnFailure=false&bridgeEndpoint=] [        37]
[xxxxxxxxxProxy    ] [stopWatchStop     ] [bean[StopWatchBean{elapsed=38, stopwatch=344.1 ms}]                           ] [         1]
```

I'm puzzled, why the difference, 38 vs 344, could it be due to Camel not taking Exception handling into account?